# Failed initial migration in Entity Framework Core on .NET 6 Isolated

Tags: entity-framework-core, azure-functions, .net-6.0

I'm trying to get Entity Framework Core to run the initial migration for my Azure functions app, but I'm getting the following error when running `Add-Migration Initial`:

> Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.IMigrator'. This is often because no database provider has been configured for this DbContext. A provider can be configured by overriding the 'DbContext.OnConfiguring' method or by using 'AddDbContext' on the application service provider. If 'AddDbContext' is used, then also ensure that your DbContext type accepts a DbContextOptions object in its constructor and passes it to the base constructor for DbContext.

I'm overriding `OnConfiguring` like this:

```cs
protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        => optionsBuilder.UseCosmos(
                accountEndpoint: "https://<redacted>.documents.azure.com:443/",
                accountKey: <redacted>,
                databaseName: <redacted>);
```

This is my `.csproj` file:

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <AzureFunctionsVersion>v4</AzureFunctionsVersion>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Extensions" Version="1.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker" Version="1.10.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.Http" Version="3.0.13" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Sdk" Version="1.7.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="7.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Cosmos" Version="7.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite" Version="7.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design" Version="7.0.1">
      <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" Version="7.0.1">
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
      <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json" Version="13.0.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Swashbuckle.AspNetCore" Version="6.4.0" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Update="host.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Update="local.settings.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
      <CopyToPublishDirectory>Never</CopyToPublishDirectory>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Using Include="System.Threading.ExecutionContext" Alias="ExecutionContext" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

I have tried following multiple guides online but cannot seem to fix this issue and I'm at a loss for what to try, so I think I must be missing something basic.

Comment: Try to add  `Debugger.Launch();` into your OnConfiguring method (or other place) and debug what happened.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv Thanks for the suggestion. This helped me verify that OnConfiguring is indeed being run, but I don't know what else I should check to find out more

Comment: Put condition `if (!optionsBuilder.IsConfigured) optionsBuilder.UseCosmos(...`

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv IsConfigured is indeed False when OnConfiguring is run, and it turns to true after .UseCosmos is run

Comment: I'm dumb. CosmosDB do not have schema and no migrations are supported.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv oh... that makes sense. Sorry for wasting your time, I've been scratching my head at this for way longer than I'd like to admit.